# Converting csv strings to a dictionary

Tags: c#, csv, dictionary

I have a string like this. Let this string be `x`.
Now I want to add this to a dictionary with key = name and value = date.
The problem is that this appears to be csv inside csv. If this was a text file, I could have easily done it with a readline(). But since this is a text string, I can't think of a way. I have the full control on the way the string appears(Generated with php). So I can put another character instead of \n if that is a more efficient method.

Thanks.

```
Mark,2014-09-15 14:31:43 \n
John,2014-09-15 14:38:29 \n
Kennedy,2014-09-15 13:49:13 \n
Jolly,2014-09-15 13:49:18 \n
Diana,2014-09-15 13:49:22 \n
Henry,2014-09-15 14:33:21 \n
```

Comment: Can you show your current code and explain why you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Sounds like you are having a problem because the newline string is \n instead of '\r\n'. You could try doing a replace or split on '\n'. Might be worth considering how large the file will be as well.

Comment: If you have the complete control over the generation of the string, then use | as a separator. You can call the split function with | to split the entrire string into an array, and then process the individual elements (may be another split with , this will separate the key and value)

Comment: String.Split using the line terminating character, then split or parse each record into a key value pair.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I will have to use two string.split . I didn't think of it before. Thanks :)

Comment: And, I thought \n could not be used as a separator because it's invisible. I am a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split any string using whatever separator you want. For example, in your string your separator is "\n", so you could:

```
var csv = "Mark,2014-09-15 14:31:43 \nJohn,2014-09-15 14:38:29 \nKennedy,2014-09-15 13:49:13 \nJolly,2014-09-15 13:49:18 \nDiana,2014-09-15 13:49:22 \nHenry,2014-09-15 14:33:21 \n";

var csvItems = csv.Split('\n');
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();

foreach (var item in csvItems)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
    {
        var itemParts = item.Split(',');
        dictionary.Add(itemParts[0], Convert.ToDateTime(itemParts[1]));
    }
}
```